# How to properly update tray notification icon?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-shell, system-tray, trayicon

Say, I created my icon:

```
//'ghIcon' of type HICON
ghIcon = LoadImage(m_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1), IMAGE_ICON, nCx, nCy, 0);
```

and then set it to be displayed on system tray:

```
NOTIFYICONDATA nid;
memset(&nid, 0, sizeof(nid));
nid.cbSize = sizeof(nid);
nid.hWnd = hMyWnd;
nid.uID = TRAY_ICON_ID1;
nid.uFlags = NIF_ICON;
nid.uCallbackMessage = TRAY_NOTIFICATION_ID1;
nid.hIcon = ghIcon;

Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &nid);
```

and then at some point I want to replace it with a new icon:

```
if(ghIcon)
{
    //Delete old icon first
    DestroyIcon(ghIcon);
}

//Load new icon
ghIcon = LoadImage(m_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON2), IMAGE_ICON, nCx, nCy, 0);

NOTIFYICONDATA nid;
memset(&nid, 0, sizeof(nid));
nid.cbSize = sizeof(nid);
nid.hWnd = hMyWnd;
nid.uID = TRAY_ICON_ID1;
nid.uFlags = NIF_ICON;
nid.hIcon = ghIcon;

Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, &nid);
```

My question is, can I delete the previous icon while it's still selected in system tray, like I showed above? Or, do I need to change it to something else first and then call `DestroyIcon` on it?

PS. My actual example is obviously not as simple as I showed above. I'm just curious about the concept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The system tray does not keep the `HICON` that you give it.  It makes a private copy.  So you are free to destroy the icon on your side whenever you want.  You don't have to keep it around, you could load it just before calling `Shell_NotifyIcon()`, and then destroy it immediately after `Shell_NotifyIcon()` exits.

```
nid.hIcon = LoadImage(...);
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &nid);
DestroyIcon(nid.hIcon);
```

```
nid.hIcon = LoadImage(...);
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, &nid);
DestroyIcon(nid.hIcon);
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing it out. Just curious though, where do you take this info from?

Comment: Personal experience with using notification icons in my own apps, and also public knowledge of `Shell_NotifyIcon()`'s inner workings deciphered by various sites.

Comment: Thanks again. One would think this stuff would be posted on the MSDN page for `Shell_NotifyIcon()` API, wouldn't it?